# Multiple possible relationships on table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table that contains account information for various entities in the database.  Currently the table design is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE account (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                      account_id int(11) NOT NULL,
                      account_type varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                      balance decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY  (id))
```

The account_id column references (not database enforced) one of 3 tables.  The account_type column tells the programmer which table to reference.  I do not like this approach, because I cannot enforce the relationship and the programmers can accidentally corrupt the data. I have considered doing one of the following:

Adding a nullable foreign key for each type, or dropping the account_id column and adding a cross reference table to link the account to the entities.  The account_type column would be used to tell the programmers which cross reference table to access.  Are there any other options?  What is the best practice for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try having a master identity table from which the three shared-identity tables draw their primary keys.  Your `account` table in the question would then link to the master table.  Loosely described:

```
MasterIdentity
    Id (autoincrement)
    IdentityType (string, maybe FK to a type lookup table, whatever you want)

Table1
    Id (PK, FK to MasterIdentity)
    other data

Table2
    Id (PK, FK to MasterIdentity)
    other data

Table3
    Id (PK, FK to MasterIdentity)
    other data

Account
    Id (its own identifier as you already have)
    AccountID (FK to MasterIdentity)
    other data
```

Inserting into any of the three tables would involve inserting into `MasterIdentity`, grabbing the scope identity value from the insert, and inserting into the desired table directly specifying the Id.  (This would all have to be atomic within a transaction, of course.)  Note that the Id on the three tables are not auto-increment values, you'd provide them.

Then any table which needs to refer to those three (non-overlapping, I assume) tables would have a single table to refer to which has the identity and the type, the latter of which tells you which sub-table has the rest of that record's data.

(I'm pretty sure this is called a supertype/subtype table relationship, but I can't say for certain.)